# PHP Warning: Attempt to read property "term_id" on bool

Tags: php, terms, errors

Since updating from PHP 7.4 to PHP 8, my `error_log` is now full of lines like this from a child theme I'm using:

> [17-Oct-2021 13:30:38 UTC] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "term_id" on bool in ./public_html/wp-content/themes/themename-child/functions.php on line 181

Here is the block that is throwing the error. It was used to modify the pagination so posts of a particular type (links) are not navigated.

```
// modify pagination to exclude post_format of 'link' on news/blog posts
function profound_navigation() {
    $previous = ( is_attachment() ) ? get_post( get_post()->post_parent ) : get_adjacent_post( false, '', true );
    $next     = get_adjacent_post( false, '', false );
    if ( ! $next && ! $previous ) {
        return;
    }
    $link_term = get_term_by('slug' , 'post-format-link' , 'post_format');
    $quote_term = get_term_by('slug' , 'post-format-quote' , 'post-format');

    the_post_navigation(
            array(
                    'next_text' => '<span class="meta-nav">Next Article <i class="flaticon-right-arrow"></i></span><h3 class="title">%title</h3>',
                    'prev_text' => '<span class="meta-nav"><i class="flaticon-left-arrow-1"></i> Previous Article</span><h3 class="title">%title</h3>',
                    // 'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                    'excluded_terms' => array($link_term->term_id, $quote_term->term_id, 156),
            )
    );
}
```

Seems like the code still works fine, but how do I modify this code to avoid filling up my error log?

Comment: I noticed you have `post_format` and `post-format` when using `get_term_by`, is this intentional? one with dash symbol and one with underscore. This could be the issue. Do a `print_r` on `$link_term` and `$quote_term` to see what they return, one is 100% empty.

Comment: That's got it. `post-format` was empty and should've been `post_format`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your taxonomy is exist. Which is a correct taxonomy slug between `post-format` and `post_format`?

> False if $taxonomy does not exist or $term was not found.

Please see: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/#return